# How to add featured image to custom WordPress API endpoint?

Tags: php, wordpress, api

We made a custom Wordpress API endpoint, but it's missing some data that regular endpoints already have. The json reponse needs to be exactly as the standard Wordpress response. We were able to achieve part of this by using "*prepare_item_for_response( get_post(), $request )->data*". But this response is missing the embeds (see image below). Can someone explain how to properly do this?

My endpoint is missing this(formated with Firefox Developer Edition)

[image]

Standard embed(calling _embedded with **_embed**)

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&page=1&orderby=date
```

My custom endpoint(currently **_embed** does nothing)

/wp-json/custom/v1/latest_posts?_embed&meta_query[0][per_page]=10&meta_query[0][page]=1&meta_query[0][days]=60

// Register a REST route

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    //Path to meta query route
    register_rest_route( 'custom/v1', '/latest_posts/', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'custom_meta_query'
    ) );
});
```

This is the query

```
function custom_meta_query(\WP_REST_Request $request) {

    if ( isset( $_GET['meta_query'] ) ) {
        $query = $_GET['meta_query'];
        // Set the arguments based on our get parameters
        $args = [
            'posts_per_page' => $query[0]['per_page'],
            'post_type'      => 'post',
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
            'meta_key'       => 'post_views_count',
            'paged'          => $query[0]['page'],
            'order'          => 'DESC',
            'has_password'   => false,
            'post__not_in'   => get_option( "sticky_posts" ),
            'date_query'     => [
                [
                    'column' => 'post_date',
                    'after'  => $query[0]['days'] . ' days ago',
                ],
            ],
        ];

        if ( $query[0]['tags'] ) {
            $taxonomy          = get_term( $query[0]['tags'] )->taxonomy;
            $args['tax_query'] =
                [
                    [
                        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                        'field'    => 'id',
                        'terms'    => $query[0]['tags'],
                    ],

                ];
        }


        // Run a custom query
        $meta_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $meta_query->have_posts() ) {
            //Define and empty array
            $data      = [];
            $rest_post = new WP_REST_Posts_Controller( 'post' );
            // Store each post's title in the array
            while ( $meta_query->have_posts() ) {
                $meta_query->the_post();
                $data[] = $rest_post->prepare_item_for_response( get_post(), $request )->data;
            }

            // Return the data
            return $data;
        } else {
            // If there is no post
            return 'No post to show';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't remember what I did. I don't work for that company anymore.